# Magento - Special price only for one associated product

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

My question is easy, is it possible to apply special price only on ONE associated product.

Eg: I have a configurable product with 4 associated, $50 each. I want to display a special price only for size 44 for a price at $25

I tried to do that, but, in my cart, all size of this product is at $25..

Someone else have this problem?
I have magento CE 1.9.3.2

Comment: What you have set main configurable product price and simple product (means option) price.

Comment: You're asking for the main attribute? If yes, it's "size"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?